# Create existing GeoTIFF store and publish layer

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, curl

I have raster images in "data_dir/data" in GeoServer.
How to remotely create storage for them and publish layers?

I do as here: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/stores.html#adding-an-existing-shapefile

curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file:///data/sentinel/S2B_MSIL1C_20220920T082629_N0400_R021_T38VNJ_20220920T091117.SAFE/index/S2B_MSIL1C_20220920T082629_N0400_R021_T38VNJ_20220920T091117_SAFE_tif-ndvi.tif"  http://geoserver:30742/geoserver/rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/S2B_MSIL1C_20220920T082629_N0400_R021_T38VNJ_20220920T091117_SAFE_tif-ndvi/external.tif

```
*   Trying geoserver:30742...
* Connected to geoserver (geoserver) port 30742 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/S2B_MSIL1C_20220920T082629_N0400_R021_T38VNJ_20220920T091117_SAFE_tif-ndvi/external.tif HTTP/1.1
> Host: geoserver:30742
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 172
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 406 
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2022 04:05:17 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host 10.70.8.126 left intact
```

GeoServer log:

```
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/login'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/logout'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null'; against '/rest/**'
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Matched Path: /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif, QueryString: null with /rest/**
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache has no entry for basic, admin:bfa584f5598433a3c1fe16b00acc9c43
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [rememberme.GeoServerTokenBasedRememberMeServices] - Did not send remember-me cookie (principal did not set parameter '_spring_security_remember_me')
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [rememberme.GeoServerTokenBasedRememberMeServices] - Remember-me login not requested.
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache adding new entry for basic, admin:bfa584f5598433a3c1fe16b00acc9c43
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 0
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache added new entry for basic, admin:bfa584f5598433a3c1fe16b00acc9c43
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 1
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif'; to: '/rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif'  and httpMethod= PUT
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=false
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [POST, DELETE, PUT]
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/s2b_msil1c_20220922t072619_n0400_r049_t41vmj_20220922t081139_safe_tif-ndvi/external.tif'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - returning ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR
23 011 10:11:49 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 10.233.69.0 "PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/S2B_MSIL1C_20220922T072619_N0400_R049_T41VMJ_20220922T081139_SAFE_tif-ndvi/external.tif" "curl/7.79.1" "" "text/plain" 
23 011 10:11:49 TRACE  [geoserver.monitor] - Testing /rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/S2B_MSIL1C_20220922T072619_N0400_R049_T41VMJ_20220922T081139_SAFE_tif-ndvi/external.tif for monitor filtering
23 011 10:11:49 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 10.233.69.0 "PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/geotiff_rest/coveragestores/S2B_MSIL1C_20220922T072619_N0400_R049_T41VMJ_20220922T081139_SAFE_tif-ndvi/external.tif" took 63ms
23 011 10:11:49 DEBUG  [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

---

```
    23 011 10:11:52 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 011 10:11:52 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 2ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 011 10:11:57 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 011 10:11:57 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 2ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:02 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:02 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 1ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:07 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:07 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 1ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/page, QueryString: 22-1.IBehaviorListener.1-rasterStoreForm-parametersPanel-url-fileInput-dialog&_=1663927646749'; against '/web/**'
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/page, QueryString: 22-1.IBehaviorListener.1-rasterStoreForm-parametersPanel-url-fileInput-dialog&_=1663927646749 with /web/**
23 012 10:12:08 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 10.233.69.0 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/page?22-1.IBehaviorListener.1-rasterStoreForm-parametersPanel-url-fileInput-dialog&_=1663927646749" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" "http://10.70.8.126:30742/geoserver/web/wicket/page?22" "" 
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.monitor] - Testing /web/wicket/page for monitor filtering
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [geoserver.monitor] - /geoserver/web/wicket/page was filtered from monitoring
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 50 locking in mode READ
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 50 got the lock in mode READ
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 50 locking in mode READ
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 50 releasing the lock in mode READ
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
23 012 10:12:08 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 10.233.69.0 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/page?22-1.IBehaviorListener.1-rasterStoreForm-parametersPanel-url-fileInput-dialog&_=1663927646749" took 4ms
23 012 10:12:08 DEBUG  [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
23 012 10:12:12 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:12 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 1ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:16 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction task running
23 012 10:12:16 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 1
23 012 10:12:16 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction task completed
23 012 10:12:16 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 1
23 012 10:12:17 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:17 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 1ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:22 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:22 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 1ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:24 DEBUG  [geoserver.wps] - Removing statuses matching [[[ NOT [ completionTime IS NULL ] ] AND [ completionTime Before 2022-09-23T10:07Z ]] AND [[ NOT [ lastUpdated IS NULL ] ] AND [ lastUpdated Before 2022-09-23T10:07Z ]]]
23 012 10:12:27 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:27 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 2ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:32 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:32 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 19ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 4&filter=false'; against '/web/**'
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 4&filter=false with /web/**
23 012 10:12:34 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 10.233.69.0 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage?4&filter=false" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" "http://10.70.8.126:30742/geoserver/web/?1" "" 
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.monitor] - Testing /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage for monitor filtering
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.monitor] - /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage was filtered from monitoring
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 54 locking in mode READ
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 54 got the lock in mode READ
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 54 locking in mode READ
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 54 releasing the lock in mode READ
23 012 10:12:34 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 10.233.69.0 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage?4&filter=false" took 11ms
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: filter=false'; against '/web/**'
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: filter=false with /web/**
23 012 10:12:34 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 10.233.69.0 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage?filter=false" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" "http://10.70.8.126:30742/geoserver/web/?1" "" 
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.monitor] - Testing /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage for monitor filtering
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.monitor] - /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage was filtered from monitoring
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 49 locking in mode READ
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'CONFIGURATION_TRYLOCK_TIMEOUT' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 49 got the lock in mode READ
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'GEOSERVER_LOG_LOCATION' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'GEOSERVER_LOG_LOCATION' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'GEOSERVER_LOG_LOCATION' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'GEOSERVER_LOG_LOCATION' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'wicket.configuration' to be unset
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 49 locking in mode READ
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG  [org.geoserver] - Thread 49 releasing the lock in mode READ
23 012 10:12:34 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - 10.233.69.0 "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage?filter=false" took 133ms
23 012 10:12:34 DEBUG
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I think the relevant part is the next bit

Comment: i added the following lines